# Find extrema of $f=x^2+(y-2)^2$ subject to $x^2-y^2=1$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

$\psi = x^2+(y-2)^2+\lambda(x^2-y^2-1)$

Establish Lagrange Equations

$$\psi_x = 2x+\lambda(2x)=0 $$

$$\psi_y = 2y-4+\lambda(-2y)=0$$

$$\psi_\lambda = x^2-y^2-1=0$$

$\psi_x*y$

$\psi_y*x$

$\psi_x=2xy+2\lambda xy=0$

$\psi_y=2xy-4x-2\lambda xy=0$

Adding and Simplifying

$4xy-4x=0$

$xy-x=0$

$y=1$

Therefore plugging back into $\psi_\lambda$,

$x^2-1-1=0$

$x=\pm\sqrt2$

Stationary points are:
$(\sqrt2,1),(-\sqrt2,1)$

Is this the correct method, and also, how would you find the maximum and minimum? Am I correct in saying that the constraint here is a unit circle and thus the maximum is 1 and the minimum is 1?

Comment: I don't get $y=0$ as a candidate. The constraint is a hyperbola.

Comment: Looking at it again, I  think y can be zero, but only when x is also zero, my stationary point of (1,0) is incorrect? I cant see why (0,0) wouldnt work though

Comment: Are you required to use Lagrange multipliers? There is a much easier way: use the restriction to solve for $x^2$ then substitute that into the expression for $f$. You then get a polynomial expression in only $y$. Then find the extrema of that. From the restriction you can see that $y$ can be any real number, so there are no further limitations.

Comment: $(0,0)$ doesn't satisfy the constraint. You should end up with points $(\pm\sqrt{2},1)$.

Comment: Made an edit after the y=1 step. Thank you for your comments guys! Massive help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Lagrange multipliers,
$$\nabla f(x,y)=\lambda\nabla g(x,y)$$
meaning that
$$f_x(x,y)\mathbf{i}+f_y(x,y)\mathbf{j}=\lambda g_x(x,y)\mathbf{i}+\lambda g_y(x,y)\mathbf{j}$$
This gives us two equations:
$$f_x(x,y)=\lambda g_x(x,y),\quad f_y(x,y)=\lambda g_y(x,y)$$
We also know from the equation for $g(x,y)$ that
$$y=\pm\sqrt{x^2-1}$$

In this case,
$$f_x(x,y)=2x,\quad f_y(x,y)=2y-4$$
and
$$g_x(x,y)=2x,\quad g_y(x,y)=-2y$$
Therefore,
$$2x=\lambda 2x,\quad 2y-4=-\lambda2y$$
From the first equation, we have $\lambda=1$.

From there, it is easy to find $y$ and $x$. However, I don't get the same results that you did.

---

I've never yet seen Lagrange multipliers used the way you used them - writing some function $\psi$ as
$$\psi=f(x)+\lambda (g(x)-1)$$
I'm actually not sure why you included the $-1$ in there. If you go straight to
$$f(x,y)=\lambda\nabla g(x,y)$$
then it shouldn't influence the problem until you connect $x$ and $y$. Bringing it in earlier will cause some problems for you.

Comment: Ok, Ill take another look. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ive edited my original post, Ive made corrections to the method I have been taught. I thought Id prompt you as it may peak your curiosity, Thanks for all the help. I like your solution.